# C Program error with char

Tags: c

When I execute the program it asks me for my name if I put more than one letter it has an error and it shuts down and in the second one anyting I put it fails and closes instantly

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {

   char firstname[20];
   char lastname[20];
   char response[20];

   printf ("Type your first name:\n");
   scanf ("'c'",&firstname);
   printf ("\n");  
   printf ("Type your last name:\n");
   scanf ("'c'",&lastname);
   printf ("\n");

   printf ("Hi %s %s do you want to stop giving me information?\nSay Y or  N");
   scanf ("%s",&response);

   if (response == 'Y' || response == 'y'); {
      system ("pause<NULL");
   }
   printf("Thank you for using my program. Good Bye!\n\n"); 

   system ("pause<NULL");
}
```

Comment: `scanf ("'c'",&firstname)` -> `scanf ("%19s", firstname)`.

Comment: it still crashes, I use Dev c++ as the ide

Comment: It doesn't compile or your compiler should at least issue warnings.

Comment: You have more of such errors. Also, you need to fix the `if` line. See [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: It compiles and runs but when I type my name it crashes

Answer (score 1):

There are many issues:

You probably want this (untested code)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {    
   char firstname[20];
   char lastname[20];
   char response[20];

   printf ("Type your first name:\n");
   scanf ("%s", firstname);
   printf ("\n");  
   printf ("Type your last name:\n");
   scanf ("%s", lastname);
   printf ("\n");

   printf ("Hi %s %s do you want to stop giving me information?\nSay Y or  N", firstname, lastname);
   scanf ("%s",response);

   if (response[0] == 'Y' || response[0] == 'y') {
      system ("pause<NULL");
   }
   printf("Thank you for using my program. Good Bye!\n\n"); 

   system ("pause<NULL");

   return 0;
}
```

- There is no `'c'` format specifier, it's `%s`
- `scanf ("%s", &firstname)` is wrong, `firstname` is already the address of the buffer
- `response == 'y'`is wrong, `response` is the address of the buffer, you just need the first char of the buffer, that is `responde[0]`
- `if (response[0] == 'Y' || response[0] == 'y'); {`, there was a stray `;` before the `{`

Comment: Even though`scanf ("%s", firstname);` is simpler for a  learner, suggest `scanf ("%19s", firstname);` as it is easier to debug given we do not know what OP may enter.

Comment: when using the `%s` format specifier in `scanf()`, always use a max characters modifier that is one less than the length of the input buffer so the user cannot overrun the input buffer as that would result in undefined behavior that can lead to a seg fault event.  I.E. `scanf ("%19s", firstname)`

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are asking for a char input, you want a string.

tutorialspoint has a simlpe and claean example. 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_scanf.htm

Comment: That's rather a comment than an answer